# MongoDB Ops Manager

Tags: mongodb, redhat, mongodb-3.6, ops-manager

I have few questions regarding backup process in MongoDB Ops Manager

1) How backup process works ?

2) According to documentation for production do we need to have 3 dedicated servers for maintaining Ops Manager ? if yes what are the RAM,storage and Core capacity needed ?

3) We planned to implement daily backup on 6 days which is incremental and on 7th day to take full backup,
My question is, Is incremental backup possible in MongoDB through Ops Manager ?

4) If separate servers needed for ops Manager how many ops Manager servers do we need to use for prod environment ?

5) What is backup daemon and how it works ?

I have checked all details in documentation and it's kind of confusing

below details are as follows:

MongoDB enterprise version 3.6.4
OS: RHEL 7.2

Answer (score 0):

As per MongoDB Documentation [here](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/core/requirements/#onprem-hardware-requirements) This guide describes the hardware, software, and networking requirements for the servers that run the Ops Manager components.

> 1) How backup process works ?

Ops Manager backups, once started, are an ongoing and continuous process. Data is continually backed up as long as the backup remains synchronized with the database

> 2) According to documentation for production do we need to have 3
>   dedicated servers for maintaining Ops Manager ? if yes what are the
>   RAM,storage and Core capacity needed ?

The Ops Manager Application requires a dedicated [Application Database](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/reference/glossary/#term-application-database) and, if you enabled backups, [Snapshot Stores](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/reference/glossary/#term-snapshot-store).

**Ops Manager Hardware Requirements**

```
Number of Monitored Hosts   CPU Cores   RAM
Up to 400 monitored hosts    4+         15 GB
Up to 2,000 monitored hosts  8+         15 GB
More than 2,000 hosts   Contact MongoDB Account Executive   Contact MongoDB Account Executive
```

**Ops Manager Application Database Hardware Requirements**

The [Ops Manager Application Database](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/core/system-overview/#mms-application-database) runs as a three-member [replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/?_ga=2.55839339.1163632804.1526188918-1505414474.1511857758#term-replica-set) that runs on dedicated servers.

Every server that hosts the Ops Manager Application Database must meet the following hardware requirements:

```
Number of Monitored Hosts   RAM                                         Disk Capacity
Up to 400            8 GB RAM plus the RAM required for Ops Manager application 200 GB
Up to 2,000          15 GB RAM plus the RAM required for Ops Manager application    500 GB
More than 2,000 Contact your MongoDB Account Executive  Contact your MongoDB Account Executive
```

> 3) We planned to implement daily backup on 6 days which is incremental
>   and on 7th day to take full backup, My question is, Is incremental
>   backup possible in MongoDB through Ops Manager ?

Snapshot Frequency and Retention Policy
By default, Ops Manager takes a base snapshot of your data every 24 hours.

If desired, administrators can change the frequency of base snapshots to 6, 8, 12, or 24 hours. Ops Manager creates snapshots automatically on a schedule. You cannot take snapshots on demand.

Ops Manager retains snapshots for the time periods listed in the following table. If you terminate a backup, Ops Manager immediately deletes the backup’s snapshots.

```
Snapshot      Default Retention Policy  Maximum Retention Policy
Base snapshot   2 days                     5 days
Daily snapshot  0 days                     1 year
Weekly snapshot 2 weeks                    1 year
Monthly snapshot 1 month                   3 years
```

You can change a backed-up deployment’s schedule through its Edit Snapshot Schedule menu option, available through the Backup page. Administrators can change snapshot frequency and retention through the [snapshotSchedule resource in the API](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/reference/api/snapshot-schedule/). If you change the schedule to save fewer snapshots, Ops Manager does not delete existing snapshots to conform to the new schedule.

> 4) If separate servers needed for ops Manager how many ops Manager
>   servers do we need to use for prod environment ?

Each server that hosts a MongoDB instance must comply with the [Production Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/) in the MongoDB manual. MongoDB instances in Ops Manager include:

- The Ops Manager Application Database,
- Each Ops Manager Backup Daemon [head
  database](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/reference/glossary/#term-head-database), and
- Each blockstore.

Failure to configure servers according to the production notes can lead to production failure.

> 5) What is backup daemon and how it works ?

The Backup Daemon service manages the local copies of the backed-up databases and snapshots for each database. The daemon does scheduled work based on data coming into the Ops Manager from its Backup Agents. No client applications can talk directly to the daemon. Its state and job queues come from the Ops Manager Application Database.

For your further ref [here](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/core/backup-preparations/#backup-configuration-options)